# Cross browser history sync

Tags: browser, synchronization, browser-history

Is it possible to have sync browser history in major browsers (Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Safari, etc) continuously. I have looked online for addons or ideas but nothing. I know all browsers have some sort of database that store links visited, how would one sync all in a way if I am in Firefox I am still able to see Internet Explorer history?

Comment: Seems like you would need multiple add-ons plus a single "synchronizer" service running in the background. The first step would be to learn if you can programmatically read and insert history in your preferred browers.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox, Chrome and Safari all use sqlite database files that you can query. Here is a link with a few commands to print browser history. [Link](https://gist.github.com/dropmeaword/9372cbeb29e8390521c2)

And here is a link to someone who created a script to import Safari history to Chrome. [Link](https://github.com/Roman2K/hist_safari2chrome)

So it should be possible to create a script that could sync at least those browsers.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.xbrowsersync.org/

*Not tried it yet, so let me know and update this answer.*